# Transform two columns data into one col with additional column type

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following data frame:

```
  Letter TimesInChapt1 TimesInChapt2
      A           100           111
      B           200           222
      C           300           333
```

I would like to transform it into the following:

```
  Letter        Times     ChapterNum
      A           100           1
      B           200           1
      C           300           1
      A           111           2
      B           222           2
      C           333           2
```

Here is the dput.

```
structure(list(Letter = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"
), class = "factor"), TimesInChapt1 = c(100, 200, 300), 
TimesInChapt2 =     c(111, 
222, 333)), .Names = c("Letter", "TimesInChapt1", "TimesInChapt2"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can likely get it to work using rbind, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution I don't know about. The tricky part is saving which column the data came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`. First we `gather` to make the data long rather than wide, then we `extract_numeric` to get only the numeric part of the chapter:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% gather(ChapterNum, Times, -Letter) %>%
        mutate(ChapterNum = extract_numeric((ChapterNum)))

  Letter ChapterNum Times
1      A          1   100
2      B          1   200
3      C          1   300
4      A          2   111
5      B          2   222
6      C          2   333
```

Answer (score 1):

People say that the `reshape` function in base R is difficult to learn, and for some applications, it can be a challenge. However, if your data are already nicely structured, as in this case, using it is a breeze:

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "long", idvar = "Letter", varying = 2:3, sep = "")
#     Letter time TimesInChapt
# A.1      A    1          100
# B.1      B    1          200
# C.1      C    1          300
# A.2      A    2          111
# B.2      B    2          222
# C.2      C    2          333
```

You can also try `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package, which can be used like:

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = "TimesInChapt", sep = "var.stubs")
```